# How to save a Higher accurate K-means Model on a unlabelled data based on Any Performance Evaluation Metrics?

Tags: clustering, k-means, model-evaluation, unsupervised-learning

I am experimenting on Iris dataset. I am not using the label. I want to save my model based on any Performance Metrics. According to Performance Metrics which model have higher score I am choosing that and then I am again running it and this time I am checking the accuracy with the actual Label.

---

Problem is for all the variation I am getting the same score

For IRIS DATA set I am getting score for every run as follows:

**SSE** :- 78.85566582597731

**Silhouette Score(n=3)**: 0.5511916046195916

**Davis-Bouldin Score** : 0.6660385791628485

**Calinski-harabasz score**: 561.593732015664

---

But for every iteration I am getting accuracy different.

So How can I be able to find for which set of centroid my model is working fine??

Comment: Could you explained more what you have tried and what you want to compare ? Do you keep all features ? have you done some feature transformation ? Have you run kmeans n=3 only or also other algorithms and parameters. Could you include some code ? After runnnig kmeans n=3 you will get the 3 best centroids for this algorithm and for value of n=3.

Comment: My question is for unlabelled data how can i measure performance of a Kmeans model? By these SSE :- 78.85566582597731

Silhouette Score(n=3): 0.5511916046195916

Davis-Bouldin Score : 0.6660385791628485

Calinski-harabasz score: 561.593732015664 .................. I  am not able to make any idea abot my model for n= 3 it is always remaining same Although when I measuring accuracy(y_pred,y_actual) for each case I am getting different accuracy. In short for same SSE/ Silhoutte Score/DB score/CH score   i am getting different accuracies. My aim is to fix this.

Comment: Clustering unlabelled data and Classification of labelled data algorithms works differently.  Clustering is aimed at finding well separated groups. If you plot some Iris data you can seee that in some cases points may belong to one cluster or the other as they are very close. You need to do some feature engineering and/or switch to classification if you want to improve this. Classification can be more precise, but may also overfit. If you just apply Clustering Kmean n=3 and do not change any parameter/data it is expected you always have the same result. No surprise here.

Comment: The mesure you use like Silhouette  measure the goodness of the group separation/distance. It is very different than measuring accuracy for a Classification problem with targets. When do you use accuracy ? do you also do run another classification algorithm , if so which one (show code in question please)?

Comment: What do you mean by a "run"? How exactly do you measure accuracy?

Comment: To what extent in general internal validation indexes such as Silhouette are a good predictor for given true classes is questionable (in reality there is no guarantee whatsoever that real classes correspond to clusters found by unsupervised methods). I have done a study on this (involving Iris and the Silhouette and others), see here   https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.03645 To appear in Advances in Data Analysis and Classification.

Comment: @Malo I agree with your point "If you just apply Clustering Kmean n=3 and do not change any parameter/data it is expected you always have the same result". I know I will get better result by applying another methods or preprocessing or doing some sort of feature engg. That is not my aim. My aim  is to find   How could I tell for any Unlabelled data , that this model works fine , as I have unlabelled datset so it is impossible for me to TUNE the Kmeans checking in which the accuracy is getting higher.

Comment: Sorry but it makes little sense to try measuring accuracy in a real context of unsupervised learning. You have to work whith the measures your already calculated. Please re-read the final question your asked and reword it to make it clear what is your real problem and objective:  "So How can I be able to find for which set of centroid my model is working fine??"